# How is the graph of $cot(x)$ valid for negative values of $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

[image: The graph of cotx]

In the graph, consider a point between $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $-\pi$. We know that $cot(x) = \frac{cos(x)}{sin(x)}$. For negative values of $x$, i.e., $cos(-x)$ is always positive and $sin(-x)$ is always negative (as the angle lies in the IV quadrant).  Now, shouldn't the value of $cot(x)$ be negative in $-\pi \lt x \lt -\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about the following range:
$$-\pi < x < -\frac{\pi}{2}$$
If we add $2\pi$ to everything, we have the same angle, so this is the same range as:
$$\pi < x < \frac{3\pi}{2}$$
Thus, we are in Quadrant III, where both $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are negative, so $\cot x$ is positive.

Comment: But in the graph, we didn't exactly add $2\pi$ to everything. The value of $x$ lied between $-\pi$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Yes, but if you look at angles between $-\pi$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, they are in Quadrant III, not Quadrant IV. For example, [here is a picture of $-\frac{2\pi}{3}=120^\circ$ begin in Quadrant III](http://media.wiley.com/Lux/64/282464.image5.jpg). The reason I added $2\pi$ to the range is because it's easier to work with positive angles than negative angles.

Comment: Got it, thanks! :)

Comment: @NobleMushtak Is cot(0) +infinity or -infinity ?